# Expected number of women sitting next to at least one man?

Tags: probability, random-variables

There are $10$ seats, $5$ men and $5$ women who randomly occupy these seats. I have to calculate the **expected** number of women sitting next to *at least one man*.

**My attempt:** I defined a random variable $X_i$ which takes value $0$ if seat number $i$ is occupied by a woman and all adjacent seats are occupied by women, and $1$ otherwise.

For a corner seat, my expected value of $X_1$ turned out to be $(5/9)$
Because probability that one man occupies seat $2$ given seat $1$ is occupied by a woman is $5/9$.

For the non-corner seats, I calculated the expected value of $X_2$ to be $(15/18)$

Because the probability that seat $2$ is occupied by a woman and at least one of seat $1$ and $3$ is occupied by a man is $1-($prob all three occupied by women$)$

I calculated the final expected value of $X$ by adding all the expected values of $X_i$ (for $i=1,2...10$) and obtained $(70/9)$. This is obviously wrong, since the number of total women cannot be less than the expected number of women sitting next to at least one man. I'd like to know where I have made the error

Comment: Use indicator random variables $Y_i$, where $i$ goes from $1$ to $5$, and $Y_i$ is $1$ if woman $i$ is sitting next to at least one man.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: That's one possibility, but the OP was pursuing another approach; though the execution was flawed, the basic idea of using an indicator variable per seat is just as valid as using an indicator variable per woman.

Comment: @joriki: Agreed, but the seats approach is more complicated and not risk free, while the approach I suggested is very quick. The comment was not intended to be an answer to OP's specific question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You had a good idea, but it's not quite right. You're counting not only seats occupied by women not surrounded by women but also all seats occupied by men. (You also didn't execute the idea correctly – for corner seats you calculated a conditional probability, and for interior seats I'm not sure exactly what you calculated.)

Here are three correct ways to solve the problem:

1) Perhaps most similar to what you tried to do, we can count the number of seats occupied by a woman and adjacent to at least one man. This is the probability for the seat to be occupied by a woman minus the probability for the seat to be occupied and surrounded by women. For a corner seat, this is

$$
\frac12-\frac{\binom83}{\binom{10}5}=\frac5{18}\;.
$$

For an interior seat, it's

$$
\frac12-\frac{\binom72}{\binom{10}5}=\frac5{12}\;.
$$

The total is

$$
2\cdot\frac5{18}+8\cdot\frac5{12}=\frac{35}9\;.
$$

2) Similarly, you can count the number of seats occupied and surrounded by women, and subtract that from the total number of women. For a corner seat, this is

$$
\frac{\binom83}{\binom{10}5}=\frac29\;,
$$

for an interior seat, it's

$$
\frac{\binom72}{\binom{10}5}=\frac1{12}\;,
$$

and so the expected value is again

$$
5-\left(2\cdot\frac29+8\cdot\frac1{12}\right)=\frac{35}9\;.
$$

3) Alternatively, you could focus on the women instead of the seats. Each woman has a probability of $\frac2{10}$ of being in a corner seat, and then she has a probability of $\frac59$ of sitting next to a man, and a probability of $\frac8{10}$ of being in an interior seat, and then she has a probability of

$$
1-\frac{\binom72}{\binom94}=\frac56
$$

of sitting next to a man, again for a total of

$$
5\left(\frac2{10}\cdot\frac59+\frac8{10}\cdot\frac56\right)=\frac{35}9\;.
$$

Comment: Upvoted! (+1). Your answer helped me spot a mistake in my generating function.

Comment: For $3)$, why is it that the probability of of a woman sitting in an interior seat and sitting next to a man $1-\binom{7}{2}/\binom{9}{4}?$ I follow the everything, but that.

Answer (score 1):

What  follows is  definitely not  the  simplest approach  but it  does
showcase generating  function methods. Let  $z$ represent men  and $w$
represent women and  $v$ women who are  not next to a man  then we get
the generating function (this is like flipping coins)

$$G(z, w, v) =
(1 + vw + v^2 w^2 + v^3 w^3 + \cdots)
\\ + (1 + w + v w^2 + v^2w^3 + \cdots)
(z + z^2 + \cdots)
\times \left(\sum_{q\ge 0}
\left(w + w^2 + v w^3 + v^2 w^4 + \cdots\right)^q
(z+z^2+z^3+\cdots)^q\right)
\times (1 + w + v w^2 + v^2 w^3 + v^3 w^4 + \cdots).$$

This is

$$G(z, w, v) = \frac{1}{1-vw} +
\left(1 + w + \frac{vw^2}{1-vw}\right)\frac{z}{1-z}
\\ \times \left(\sum_{q\ge 0} \left(w + \frac{w^2}{1-vw}\right)^q
\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^q\right)
\left(1 + w + \frac{vw^2}{1-vw}\right)
\\ = \frac{1}{1-vw} +
 \frac{1 + (1-v)w}{1-vw}
\frac{z}{1-z}
\frac{1}{1-(w+w^2(1-v))z/(1-vw)/(1-z)}
\frac{1 + (1-v)w}{1-vw}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-vw} + \frac{1}{1-vw}
\frac{z(1+(1-v)w)^2}{(1-z)(1-vw)-(w+w^2(1-v))z}
\\ = \frac{1+(1-v)wz}{(1-z)(1-vw)-(w+w^2(1-v))z}.$$

Now as a sanity check put $z=w$ and $v=1$ to obtain

$$\frac{1}{(1-z)^2 - z^2} = \frac{1}{1-2z}$$

and the check goes through, we have $2^n$ possible sequences.

Following the usual procedure we compute
$$\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial v}
G(z, w, v)\right|_{v=1}.$$

We obtain

$$-\frac{wz}{(1-z)(1-vw)-(w+w^2(1-v))z}
\\- \frac{1+(1-v)wz}{((1-z)(1-vw)-(w+w^2(1-v))z)^2}
(-w + wz + w^2z).$$

Setting $v=1$ now yields

$$-\frac{wz}{(1-z)(1-w)-wz}
- \frac{-w+wz+w^2z}{((1-z)(1-w)-wz)^2}
\\ = -\frac{wz}{(1-z-w)}
- \frac{-w+wz+w^2z}{(1-z-w)^2}
= \frac{w(1-z)^2}{(1-z-w)^2}.$$

Prepare for coefficient extraction on $[z^n w^n]:$

$$[z^n] [w^n]
\frac{w}{(1-w/(1-z))^2}
= [z^n] [w^{n-1}]
\frac{1}{(1-w/(1-z))^2}
\\ = [z^n] \frac{n}{(1-z)^{n-1}}
= n {n+n-2\choose n-2}
= n \times {2n-2\choose n-2}.$$

Therefore the expected number of women that are not next to a man is

$${2n\choose n}^{-1} \times n \times {2n-2\choose n-2}
= \frac{n! \times n!}{(2n)!}
n \frac{(2n-2)!}{n!\times (n-2)!}
\\ = \frac{n!}{(2n)(2n-1)}
n \frac{1}{(n-2)!}
= \frac{1}{2} \frac{n(n-1)}{2n-1}.$$

For the women that are next to at least one man we get

$$n - \frac{1}{2} \frac{n(n-1)}{2n-1}
= \frac{n}{2} \frac{3n-1}{2n-1}.$$

Observe that the case $n=5$ produces the special value
$$\frac{35}{9}.$$

The Maple code for this computation was as follows.

```
RL :=
proc(n)
    option remember;
    local ind, d, pos, cur, run, runs, gf,
    zcnt, wcnt, vcnt;

    if n = 1 then return z + v*w fi;

    gf := 0;

    for ind from 2^n to 2*2^n-1 do
        d := convert(ind, base, 2);

        cur := -1; pos := 1;
        run := []; runs := [];


        while pos <= n do
            if d[pos] <> cur then
                if nops(run) > 0 then
                    runs :=
                    [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];
                fi;

                cur := d[pos];
                run := [cur];
            else
                run := [op(run), cur];
            fi;

            pos := pos + 1;
        od;

        runs := [op(runs), [run[1], nops(run)]];

        zcnt := add(`if`(r[1] = 0, r[2], 0), r in runs);
        wcnt := add(`if`(r[1] = 1, r[2], 0), r in runs);

        vcnt :=
        add(`if`(r[1] = 1 and r[2] > 2, r[2]-2, 0), r in runs);

        if runs[1][1] = 1 and runs[1][2] > 1 then
            vcnt := vcnt + 1;
        fi;

        if runs[-1][1] = 1 and runs[-1][2] > 1 then
            vcnt := vcnt + 1;
        fi;

        gf := gf + z^zcnt*w^wcnt*v^vcnt;
    od;

    gf;
end;

G1 :=
proc(n)
    local gf;

    gf := 1/(1-v*w) + z*(1+(1-v)*w)^2/(1-v*w)/
    ((1-z)*(1-v*w)- (w+w^2*(1-v))*z);

    expand(add(z^q*w^(n-q)*
               coeftayl(gf, [z, w]=[0,0], [q, n-q]),
               q=0..n));
end;

G2 :=
proc(n)
    local gf;

    gf := (1+(1-v)*w*z)/
    ((1-z)*(1-v*w)- (w+w^2*(1-v))*z);

    expand(add(z^q*w^(n-q)*
               coeftayl(gf, [z, w]=[0,0], [q, n-q]),
               q=0..n));
end;


H1 := n ->  subs(v=1, diff(RL(n), v));

H2 :=
proc(n)
    local gf;

    gf := -(w*z)/((1-z)*(1-w)-w*z)
    - (-w+w*z+w^2*z)/((1-z)*(1-w)-w*z)^2;

    expand(add(z^q*w^(n-q)*
               coeftayl(gf, [z, w]=[0,0], [q, n-q]),
               q=0..n));
end;

X1 :=
proc(n)
    coeftayl(subs(v=1, diff(RL(2*n), v)), [z, w]=[0, 0],
             [n, n]);
end;

X2 := n -> n*binomial(2*n-2,n-2);

Y1 := n -> X1(n)/binomial(2*n,n);
Y2 := n -> 1/2*n*(n-1)/(2*n-1);
```

Comment: +1! I think I'll try repairing my sink using generating functions -- there seems to be nothing they can't do :-) Just one slight improvement: Instead of

$$
1+w+\frac{vw^2}{1-vw}
$$

you could have written

$$
1+\frac w{1-vw}
$$

(twice).

Comment: Thank you for this important and kind remark. As my edit cycle is now ended I will keep it as is and let the reader discover your insight. While generating functions are admittedly more machinery than what is needed here they also show how these problems can be solved automagically by computer algebra systems. I do admit that it is a special moment when the generating function matches the data from total enumeration as seen in the Maple code.